# Direct comparison test condition

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I tried to use direct comparison test to check whether it converges or diverges, I always confuse how to find the inequalities 
1. $\int_0^\pi\frac{dt} {\sqrt t+sin x}\, \mathrm dx,$ 
for
$0\le t \le\pi$, $0 \le \frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$
and 
2. $\int_\pi^\infty\frac{1+sin x} {x^2}\, \mathrm dx,$ 

 $0\le \frac{1+sinx}{x^2} \le \frac{2}{x^2}$, for $x \geq \pi$ 
is this because $0 \le sinx \le 1$?

 can someone explain to me how can I get this condition?

Comment: For the first one, notice that $$0\le x\le\pi\implies 0\le\sin(x)\le 1$$ and for the second $$-1\le\sin(x)\le 1$$ You can use these along with a bit of algebra to get the bounds.

Comment: @kajelad thankyou for answering my question! for the first one,$ 0\le x\le\pi\implies 0\le\sin(x)\le 1$ then $0\le\sin(x) + \sqrt t \le  \sqrt t $ then $0 \le \frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ but why not the sign $\le$ change to $\geq$? since it is fraction(?) and do you get the condition according to $ 0\le x\le\pi$?

Comment: taking a reciprocal flips the inequality. That is, for any $a,b>0$, we have: $$a\le b \implies \frac 1a\ge \frac 1b$$ Essentially, a larger denominator indicates a smaller value,

Comment: @kajelad $0 \le \frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ why it is not flip here? since $\frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t}$ has larger denominator?

Comment: That would be correct. The reasoning goes like $$0\le t\le \pi$$ $$\implies \sin(t)\ge 0$$ $$\implies\sqrt t+\sin(t)\ge \sqrt t$$ $$\implies\frac 1{\sqrt t+\sin(t)}\le\frac 1{\sqrt t}$$ Since the denominator is positive, $$0\le \frac 1{\sqrt t+\sin(t)}\le\frac 1{\sqrt t}$$

Comment: @kajelad thanks but i still dont get the point! but why you use $\sin(t)\ge 0$ ? is it possible using this inequalities $0\le x\le\pi\implies 0\le\sin(x)\le 1$ ,$\sqrt t \le\sin(x) + \sqrt t \le 1+ \sqrt t$ , $\frac{1}{\sqrt t + 1} \le \frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$?

Comment: Sure, but you don't really need the lower bound, since $0$ works just as well for Comparison test.

Comment: @kajelad do you mean the lower bound is $\frac{1}{\sqrt t + 1}$ ? i was so confuse $0 \le \frac {1}{\sqrt t +sin t} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$ why the lower bound is zero and not $\frac{1}{\sqrt t + 1}$